# Storing ticks in DateTime from C# to Mongo

Tags: c#, mongodb

C# represents DateTimes with a high level of precision, using the ticks metric. Mongo seems to serialize to a milliseconds epoch format, which loses some of the precision.

Does anyone know how I can override the DateTime serializer in the MongoDb BsonSerializer to store the ticks as well as the DateTime so I don't lose precision when serializing and de-serializing a DateTime?

My attempt

```
// http://techqa.info/programming/question/16185262/What-is-new-way-of-setting-DateTimeSerializationOptions-Defaults-in-mongodb-c--driver-
var serializer = new DateTimeSerializer(DateTimeKind.Utc, BsonType.Document);
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(typeof(DateTime), serializer);
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(typeof(DateTime?), serializer);
```

EDIT: Putting the attribute

```
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Document)]
```

On each individual field of the objects being serialized seems to work, but I don't want to go through every document and do it, I want to set it at the application level for all DateTimes. I thought the above code lines would do that but they don't seem to be being used.

Comment: Why not just store the DateTime.Ticks into a Mongo 'NumberLong'?

Comment: Possible, but then you lose the ability to see it as a Date in Mongo for debugging and to do Date functions in queries